# Modal Bottom Sheet with Peek Height

Tags: android-jetpack-compose, bottom-sheet, jetpack-compose-modalbottomsheet

[image]

I had design where bottom sheet is with certain peek height when it is fully collapsed. And fill entire height when it is expanded.
How to implement this design using Modal Bottom Sheet (Jetpack Compose M3) ?

```
            val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = false)
            val scope = rememberCoroutineScope()

            Scaffold() {
                WeatherView(api = api)
                ModalBottomSheet(
                        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
                        sheetState = sheetState,
                        onDismissRequest = {scope.launch { sheetState.partialExpand() }.invokeOnCompletion {
                            if (sheetState.targetValue == SheetValue.Hidden) {
                            }
                        }},
                        shape = RoundedCornerShape(
                            topStart = 20.dp,
                            topEnd = 20.dp
                        ),
                        containerColor = Color.White.copy(0.2f),
                        dragHandle = {
                            BottomSheetDefaults.DragHandle(
                                width = 48.dp,
                                height = 5.dp,
                                color = Color.Black.copy(0.3f)
                            )
                        }
                    ) {
                        BottomSheetContent()
                    }
                }
        }
```

Answer (score 2):

If I understand your question correct, you have at least 2 options to set height of ModalBottomSheet:

1. Apply modifier `fillMaxHeight` to `ModalBottomSheet` with required fraction if height should be based on percentage:

```
modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.5f) // 50% of height
```

2. Apply modifier `height` to `ModalBottomSheet` with required height in `Dp`:

```
modifier = Modifier.height(80.dp)
```

Full example with height based on fraction:

```
@Composable
private fun Content() {
    var bottomSheetIsOpen by rememberSaveable { mutableStateOf(false) }

    Scaffold {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier
                .padding(it)
                .fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "Screen content"
            )
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = {
                    bottomSheetIsOpen = true
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Show BottomSheet"
                )
            }
        }
    }

    if (bottomSheetIsOpen) {
        BottomSheet(
            closeBottomSheet = {
                bottomSheetIsOpen = false
            }
        )
    }
}

@OptIn(ExperimentalMaterial3Api::class)
@Composable
private fun BottomSheet(
    closeBottomSheet: () -> Unit
) {
    val sheetState = rememberModalBottomSheetState(skipPartiallyExpanded = true)
    val coroutineScope = rememberCoroutineScope()

    ModalBottomSheet(
        modifier = Modifier.fillMaxHeight(0.5f),
        sheetState = sheetState,
        onDismissRequest = closeBottomSheet
    ) {
        Column(
            modifier = Modifier.fillMaxSize(),
            verticalArrangement = Arrangement.Center,
            horizontalAlignment = Alignment.CenterHorizontally
        ) {
            Text(
                text = "BottomSheet content"
            )
            ElevatedButton(
                onClick = {
                    coroutineScope.launch {
                        sheetState.hide()
                    }.invokeOnCompletion {
                        closeBottomSheet()
                    }
                }
            ) {
                Text(
                    text = "Close"
                )
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Result:

[image]

Comment: Actually that is not what I mean. What I want is when the bottom sheet collapsed, it will still appeared with certain height. Not hidden. When it is expand, still expand on the entire screen height. However I has solved it partly using Bottom Sheet Scaffold, thank you for the help anyway